# Move objects with the mouse using Manipulate in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mouse

I would like to create a little game where user would simply move some images around with their mouse to create some shapes.

I found about this possibility in the [Nutts Puzzle](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NuttsPuzzle/) Demo by Karl Scherer.

However looking into the source code I can`t figure out which part enable to manipulate the shapes with the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very last control statement in the manipulate is

```
{{pts, {{2, 1.5}, ..., {16.1, 16.1}}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
```

This makes an invisible [Locator](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html) at the center of each polygon.
It is these that are picked up and moved by the mouse.

The preceding controls create the 2 popup menus and the 19 rotation sliders.

---

**Edit:** To address the comment, an example using `Inset`:

```
g[1]=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Girl"}];
g[2]=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Girl2"}];
g[3]=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Girl3"}];
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[x^n],{x,0,4Pi},
    Epilog->Table[Inset[g[i],pos[[i]],{0,0},ImageScaled[{.2,.2}]],{i,3}]],
  {{n, 1}, 0, 4},
  {{pos,{{0,0},{Pi,0},{2Pi,0}}},Locator,Appearance->None}]
```

[image: Girls on Cos]

Bonus points: Name the "Girl"s in the "TestImage" example data...

Comment: many thanks for your explanation, now it make sense. do you know if I could use Locator with an Image.  Image not being a Graphics primitive ?

Comment: @500: You'd have to position the image in your `Graphics` using [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html). The position of the `Inset` can be attached to a `Locator` in the same way as any other graphics object.

Comment: I give up for I need to work but I am sure the solution lies somewhere here : http://www.hecklerspray.com/the-26-hottest-star-trek-babes/200816466.php   or here  http://allyourtrekarebelongto.us/toswomen.htm   ;)

Comment: Ok I believed I have browsed those two links without success :( Who is She !?

Answer (score 2):

For example, this

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Disk[p, .2], PlotRange \[Rule] {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}],
   {{p, {.2, 1.5}}, Locator, Appearance \[Rule] None}]
```

displays a circle; when you click somewhere, the circle jumps there. Does this answer the question?

Comment: thank you ! Is there a way to manipulate image without graphics ? Image does not seem to be a Graphics primitive...

Comment: @500 yes, the way Simon described. Maybe post a toy version of your problem?

Comment: Yes, i will post either with web.mathematica or through the Demonstration project as soon as i have something decent to show soon hopefully !

Comment: @500 no I mean something really downsized, so that someone could explicitly show you how to use Locator objects with Images

Comment: oh I am now using bothe yours and Simon answer with sucess, it is working !